# How can I opt out of blank paragraph insertion in CKEDITOR?

Tags: ckeditor

I posted a related note at [How can I clean up Django bleach + CKeditor debris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844571/how-can-i-clean-up-django-bleach-ckeditor-debris) about how to remove encroaching blank paragraphs from Python / Django.

However, I'd like to more directly ask if CKeditor affords the functionality to opt-out of blank paragraphs being added, or to remove all blank paragraphs before submit.

An example of the HTML source with one programmatically added blank paragraph (the indented lines are indented by one tab, not by spaces):

```
<p>
    This little bunny is <em>shy</em>, but also very affectionate.</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    Would you like to meet her?</p>
```

I get one added paragraph per save.

How can I prevent, rule out, etc. addition of blank paragraphs other than at the user's initiative?

Thanks,

Comment: Jonathan, it is not clear how to reproduce the issue. What exactly do you do to get this empty paragraph added?

Comment: I have a Django admin site. Several of the fields represented get a TEXTAREA widget. I've hijaxed those fields by, after importing CKeditor, calling a loop iterating over TEXTAREAs with ``CKEDITOR.replace(textareas[index].name);``.

Comment: If I have only one paragraph, everything works great. If I break a line into two paragraphs and click "Save and Continue Editing", it brings me to the pages with a blank paragraph separating them; then I get one additional blank paragraph per time I click "Save and Continue Editing" or equivalent.

Comment: One other note that I might be tripping CKeditor up on: I want to provide richly edited text that is at some times inline and an automatic line / paragraph break for what would ordinarily be put together logically as a single line or paragraph, leaves things artificially sliced up.

Comment: I remove initial opening / final closing tags after CKeditor edited, which let me display things inline as desired. Is CKeditor allergic to removal of the string's opening '<p>' and closing '</p>'? Should I be using another approach to request rich text editing for inline deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the opening and final closing tags before storing in your DB, which leaves mismatched html tags and therefore invalid html (...whenever you have more than one `p` block). So,

```
<p>Something</p>
<p>Something else</p>
```

becomes:

```
Something</p>  // invalid html - closing tag with no corresponding opening tag
<p>Something else  // invalid html - opening tag with no corresponding closing tag
```

CKEditor is actually trying to fix the invalid html for you when loaded back into the editor.

If you don't want paragraph tags I'd suggest using the config option `config.autoParagraph = false;` and/or `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;` (CKEditor will use a `<br />` instead when the user types a new line) just depending on your requirements.

Another possible solution would be to change your function before the save to do a find and replace of all occurrences of `'<p>'` with `''` and `'</p>'` with `'<br />'`, before a final remove of any trailing `'<br />'`.

**Steps to duplicate the problem:**

A. You can go to http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/accessibilitychecker.html and click on `Source` button, and paste the following:

```
<p>Something</p>
<p>Something else</p>
```

B. Click `Source` and it will display this html correctly.

C. Click `Source` again to go back to source mode and only the 2 `p` elements will show

D. Remove the opening paragraphs and the closing paragraph tags:

```
Something</p>  // invalid html - closing tag with no corresponding opening tag
<p>Something else  // invalid html - opening tag with no corresponding closing tag
```

E Click on `Source` twice to render the output and then to see the adjusted source:

```
<p>Something</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Something else</p>
```